# How to call a method in another class using robotium

Tags: java, robotium

Using Robotium for my Android automation I find myself creating the same steps for each test case.

I always need to "Login" and "Logout", I've been trying to create a FunctionsTestClass so I can simply call rLogin(); and rLogout();

Here is an example:

Adding my complete files.

```
'package com.myproject.mobile.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.app.Activity;
import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;

import com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.By;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

'public class Logout extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity> {

private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME = "com.myproject.mobile.MainActivity";
private static Class<?> launchActivityClass;
static {
    try {
        launchActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private static ExtSolo solo; // ExtSolo is an extension of Robotium Solo that helps
                        // collecting better test execution data during test
                        // runs

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Logout() {
    super((Class<Activity>) launchActivityClass);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new ExtSolo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity(), this.getClass()
            .getCanonicalName(), getName());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    solo.tearDown();
    super.tearDown();
}


public static void logginin() throws Exception {
    try {
    //enter username
        solo.sleep(17000);

        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        solo.fail(
                "com.myproject.mobile.test.MainActivityTest.testRecorded_scr_fail",
                e);
        throw e;
    }
}

}'
```

Adding my second file

```
package com.mypackage.mobile.test;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.app.Activity;
import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;

import com.bitbar.recorder.extensions.ExtSolo;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.By;
import com.mypackage.mobile.test.*;


import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

'public class Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Activity> {

private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME =     "com.mypackage.mobile.MainActivity";
private static Class<?> launchActivityClass;

static {
    try {
        launchActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
private static ExtSolo solo; // ExtSolo is an extension of Robotium Solo that helps
                        // collecting better test execution data during test
                        // runs

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Test() {
    super((Class<Activity>) launchActivityClass);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    solo = new ExtSolo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity(), this.getClass()
            .getCanonicalName(), getName());
}

@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    solo.tearDown();
    super.tearDown();
}



public void testRecorded() throws Exception {
    try {
    
        Logout.logginin();


    } catch (AssertionFailedError e) {
        solo.fail(
                "com.mypackage.name.MainActivityTest.testRecorded_scr_fail",
                e);
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        solo.fail(
                            "com.mypackage.name.MainActivityTest.testRecorded_scr_fail",
                e);
        throw e;
    }
}

    }
```

Updated the bottom two code to reflect my project.

Comment: I was newer to programming then. What actually helped me was learning inheritance and creating a framework that can extend from the BaseClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create **testcase** with name `testLoggingin()` . Instead of that creat a **class** having **function** `login()`. So that, whenever its needed you can import it and can call the function to login. And you can check conditions using `assert`.

Comment: Are you saying to change testLoggingin() to login() and then import com.my.package.name.test.Functional on my test.java class, then call login() from the Functional class?

Comment: Not exactly... You can define a function in a different class (it should be a normal class, not a testcase) which could be called in any of the testcases wherever login is needed. It would save you from writing the same code again and again. It would work fine.

Comment: `solo.waitForActivity("MainActivity");
        solo.waitForActivity("LoginActivity");` is written twice.
That is why your code is not working..use it in only one place.
Hope it will work. either remove it from `testRecorded()` or from  `testLoggingin()` depending upon your convenience.

Comment: I have removed the solo.waitForActiviy, without luck. I've trouble shooted for awhile now,   if the only call inside Logout.testLoggingin() is solo.sleep(25000); the test case still  instantly fails.

Comment: Also, I tried to create just a class without extending the testcases, my solo + Asserts throw errors.

Thank you for helping, I am new to java.

Comment: I have added my complete files above in the main post.  I'm simply trying to call solo.sleep(20000); // 20 seconds except it fails instantly when it gets to this step? 

My main class is calling the Logout.loggingin(); but I have an instant fail.  a

Comment: the way you have written the class **Logout** is not proper. This is actually a kind of testcase just renamed as Logout. Delete this Logout class and create a new Logout class which should not extend any activity, it should not try to launch any activity, its hould not have any setup and teardown function.

Comment: `package com.myproject.mobile.test;
import android.widget.*;
public class Logout{
public static void logginin()
{
//use solo class to
//enter username
//click on submit button
}
}`

now if you call this function in your testcase, it will work. :)